# Error starting Asp.Net Core MVC app in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a strange error when starting brand new ASP.NET Core MVC project. Iisespresstray is throwing this exception at each startup :

```
System.ArgumentException: Le nom de répertoire C:\Users\ThiCOMPUTERNAME=CODBOOK\ n'est pas valide.
   à System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path(String value)
   à Microsoft.IisExpress.SysTray.TrayAppHiddenForm.TrayAppHiddenForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

"Thi" is the start of my username and "CODEBOOK" the machine name.

It sounds like an environment variable mismatch, but I'm unable to find where ?

Despite this error, IisExpress starts and the web app is correctly served...

I don't have this issue with ASP.NET 4 MVC projects.